# How to Import all excel files in an order list in python?

Tags: python, excel, list

I have read all the links that were suggested by stackoverflow. I have problem while importing excel files from a folder.  I have used 
 this `files=os.listdir(path)` in my code. But i am not sure why the list is irregular.

I have imported every file from a folder by defining the path. All the 350 files were imported but the list formation is irregular which are not in order as that of order in folder.

The code i have written is this:

```
path="C:/Nutakki/All_set/excel files/episode0/"
files=os.listdir(path)
print(files)
#m=['paketone4000.dump.xlsx','paketone8000.dump.xlsx','paketone1400000.dump.xlsx']
#fig_name=['i4000','i8000','i12000']
#
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) ##to obtain figure and dimensions of graph

for index, i in enumerate(files):


    #ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') ## to have a broad view of figure
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')

    #plot planes
    p = Rectangle((0,-0.7), 4.5,1.4, color="lightgrey", alpha=0.2) #plots the background frame
    ax.add_patch(p)

    art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

    j=pd.read_excel(i)  ##to read the excel file format
    X=j['x'] ## to import the variable on to axes from data set
    Y=j['y']
    Z=j['z']
    #ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='g', marker='o') ## to specify the color and shape of point(marker) of the frame
#    print(j)
    a=j['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
    b=j['y']
    c=j['z']

    q1=j['q1'],##attaining quaternons from excel file format. (comma(,) transformed series to tuple)
    q2=j['q2'],
    q3=j['q3'],
    q4=j['q4'],

    m2,n,o,p=np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4]) ## assigning quaternions to variables had converted tuple to float
    Rot_Mat=QtoR(m2,n,o,p)

    #cuboid initialising parameters
    center = [a[0], b[0], c[0]] ##centre of the body
    length = 0.3 ##defining length, breadth, height
    width = 0.4
    height = 0.1
    side = np.zeros((8,3))  ###This numpy vector will be used to store the position of the sides

    #rotate the axes and update
    for angle in range(0, 360):
        ax.view_init(90, angle)

    cuboid(center, (length, width, height)) #to execute the defined cuboid
    print('file_no:',i)
```

After executing this i got the list as follows:

```
['paketone0.dump.xlsx', 'paketone100000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1000000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1004000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1008000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1012000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1016000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1020000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1024000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1028000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1032000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1036000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone104000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1040000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1044000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1048000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1052000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1056000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1060000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1064000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1068000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1072000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1076000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone108000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1080000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1084000.dump.xlsx',...........]
```

The expected result should be in this list format

```
['paketone0.dump.xlsx','paketone4000.dump.xlsx','paketone8000.dump.xlsx','paketone12000.dump.xlsx','paketone16000.dump.xlsx','paketone20000.dump.xlsx','paketone24000.dump.xlsx','paketone28000.dump.xlsx','paketone32000.dump.xlsx','paketone36000.dump.xlsx','paketone40000.dump.xlsx','paketone44000.dump.xlsx','paketone48000.dump.xlsx',...........]
```

As my files are this order packtone(0 to 1400000).dump.xlsx in the folder.

Comment: `I have read all the links that were suggested by you` Who are you talking to?

Comment: I mean to the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sort the final list in your way

```
import re
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = "C:/Nutakki/All_set/excel files/episode0/"
m = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+")
m = sorted(m, key = lambda m :  int(pattern.findall(m)[0]) )
```

output is

```
['paketone0.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone100000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone104000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1000000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1004000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1008000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1012000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1016000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1020000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1024000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1028000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1032000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1036000.dump.xlsx',
 'paketone1040000.dump.xlsx']
```

Comment: As you have specified `m= ['paketone0.dump.xlsx', 'paketone100000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1000000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1004000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1008000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1012000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1016000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1020000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1024000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1028000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1032000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1036000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone104000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1040000.dump.xlsx']` a list like this in your code. I have the files of almost 3000 files, so rather than giving file name i want to import directly from a folder that also in an order.

Comment: You need to read in all of the file names in a list and sort them in order, then use them in order.

Comment: ok, as you have edited your answer i will check with that. One more thing can you please retype my full code by attaching with your code. So, that i can know how the process is going on.

Comment: Ok, now i got the excel files in order. In my case i will obtain an image for a particular excel file. Like that i should obtain 300 images with different names. **Note:** as the excel files are also 300

Comment: If you got more questions, start a new one on StackOverflow.

Comment: @NUTAKKIPRADEEPCHAKRAVARTHI Could you accept the answer if it helps?

Comment: The question going on same thing..... i need the help.....anyways i have accepted the answer

Comment: @NUTAKKIPRADEEPCHAKRAVARTHI `import re; pattern = re.compile(r"\d+");
m= ['paketone0.dump.xlsx', 'paketone100000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1000000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1004000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1008000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1012000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1016000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1020000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1024000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1028000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1032000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1036000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone104000.dump.xlsx', 'paketone1040000.dump.xlsx'];
sorted(m, key = lambda m : pattern.findall(m)[0])`  This is the reproducible part.

Comment: @NUTAKKIPRADEEPCHAKRAVARTHI As you said, you already got the list m. then my solution is to sort the list. what else problem you got, you need to ask another question.

Comment: After this i have added this .````df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, filename in enumerate(files):
    data = pd.read_excel(filename)  ##to read the excel file format
    print(filename)
    df = df.append(data,ignore_index = True)```` Now i want to read the excel  in this form                                                                                                             ```` df = pd.read_excel(filename, header = [0],skiprows = [1,2],\
                   parse_dates = ['Time'], date_parser = my_date_parser) ````    can i do like this?